# System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly' - C# / C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli, porting, asp.net-core-6.0

I try to be as detailed as possible in explaining our situation, premising that we made several attempts in relation to other similar situations found on stackoverflow. Specifically, we have a project consisting of many libraries in c# that has been updated from net 4.7 to asp.netcore 6.0. Within the project there is also a library of classes in c++. This library generates a dll that is used within one of the projects c#. The project in c++ has not been updated, but we simply went to vary the target framework from net 4.7 to netcore 6.0 (and also we changed clr to clr:netcore) as explained in the Microsost guide for porting hybrid projects in C# and C++. All the project builds correctly but when the debugging of the webapp in C# referencing the dll in C++ I get the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Tradante.MT4.Wrapper, Version=1.0.8369.22669, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.'
```

Navigating through various issues similar to our case, we seemed to understand that the incompatibility problem could be related to having a project at x64 and another at x86. We tried to vary all possible combinations but the error remains the same. But we noticed something strange: we forced the build to x64 of the webapp in C# but in the compilation output (which we see as enabled debugging of the native code) we find the name of the webapp followed by (Win32) as if the machine continues to build at x86. I don’t know if this information can help you.

Comment: You have a question about building, but don't specify your build environment.

Comment: I've seen this exception when mixing up x86 and x64 assemblies.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield our build environment is Windows

Comment: Well no kidding; are you building from the command line, using Visual Studio, using make files, what???

Comment: @MarkBenningfield VisualStudio

Comment: Open "Configuration Manager" and make sure that the C++ dlls are set to build for the right platform when the current target platform is built.